# VB.net 4. Automapper mapping one-to-many to one-to-one-to-many

Tags: vb.net, automapper

I have a POCO/DTO which is a one-to-many relationship like this:

```
Public Class Main1
    Public A As Integer
    Public Subs As New List(Of Sub1)
End Class

Public Class Sub1
    Public B As Integer
End Class
```

And I have a business-logic portion which looks like this:

```
Public Class Main2
    Public A As Integer
    Public Subs As New Sub2Set()
End Class

Public Class Sub2Set
    Public Subs As New List(Of Sub2)

    Public Sub Add(ByVal Sub2 As Sub2)
        'Do some validation checks here.
        Me.Subs.Add(Sub2)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Sub2
    Public B As Integer
End Class
```

I'm using a `Sub2Set` to (1) only expose methods which are relevant and (2) check to make sure the `Sub2` being added doesn't violate any of our rules.

How can I use automapper to map Main1 and its children to Main2 and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work one direction so far:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(Of Sub1, Sub2)()
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(Of List(Of Sub1), Sub2Set)().ForMember(Function(d) d.Subs, Sub(o) o.MapFrom(Function(s) s))
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(Of Main1, Main2)().ForMember(Function(d) d.Subs, Sub(o) o.ResolveUsing(Of SubResolver)())

Dim Main2 As Main2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of Main2)(Main1)
```

with a custom resolver

```
Public Class SubResolver
    Inherits AutoMapper.ValueResolver(Of Main1, Sub2Set)

    Protected Overrides Function ResolveCore(ByVal source As Main1) As Sub2Set
        Return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of Sub2Set)(source.Subs)
    End Function

End Class
```